# Solar panels for Naval ships in Ship building

Tags: ships, shipbuilding, naval-combat

As the Naval ships sail in the deep seas, oceans and they are open to the blue sky (As i visualise them), Can there be Naval ships where Solar panels could be required for them in specific cases, occasions ?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1924/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solar panels are already routinely used on some ships to charge batteries and provide power to the on board equipment. It's a common sight if you go in any harbor.

However don't forget that the ocean is not always blue sky. It can also be very cloudy, and not for all use cases you can afford to have limited power available.

As a first ballpark figure, they make sense when you have limited space and therefore cannot afford installing an additional generator plus the related fuel, and when the batteries you can put on board are enough to supply your equipment for the expect time of cloudy/dark sky.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Apart from very small scale (charging small batteries for equipment) I can't imagine Solar power to be used very much at all in a military.

This is because it is a Navy. The primary purpose of a Navy is to be able to apply force, often **in direct conflict with another Navy** (or opposing force). As such your Navy needs to be as powerful as it can be, or it would not survive against a Navy that prioritises power.

This is why often with Military hardware and assets that **efficiency takes 'second place' to lethal force** except if it is vital to a mission, which is unusual. Usually you want firepower, speed, or armour.

There may be a reason to have solar power for small equipment in the field on reconnaissance if you are far from a base- but if it is slow to charge, unreliable at all times, often needs maintenance, you would not rely on it as a Navy, because your life depends on it. **In fact military needs for power on any vessel likely exceed any power from a Solar Panel**.

A good example is the latest Zumwalt Class of destroyer. Using all-electric engines and systems is innovative however it still relies on a gas turbine to charge batteries - the power the vessel uses is far in excess of any available from the sun and it needs to be effective against other ships/militaries that use powerful fuels. The only way solar would be needed would be **a world where there is no other fuel available**, such that other Navies cannot produce more powerful ships than your own.

Answer (score 2):

### Not for Warships

According to Wikipedia, a [Los Angeles class submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles-class_submarine) has a >100 MW nuclear reactor.

A 100 MW solar farm requires about 500 - 1000 **acres** of panels.

It is not feasible for a warship to tow a massive floating array of solar panels.

### Maybe for Loitering Sensors

But Combatants aren't the only tools that a Navy needs. Distributed senors systems could potentially run on solar power. Small, self propelled buoys with attached acoustic, radar, LIDAR, visual, etc. sensors could be a major asset.

The idea is: they're cheap, so we don't care if they are slow. (and therefore likely to get shot by the enemy)

We want a lot of them, to monitor large areas, so any kind of supply chain that involves refueling them is challenging. So we need the kind of endurance that you get from a renewable energy source.

So think less battleship, and more 20 foot long sailboat with a bunch of towed arrays and antennas.

Answer (score 2):

**Every good Navy deserves Drone Boats.**

**[image]**

https://www.nauticexpo.com/boat-manufacturer/marine-drone-23029.html

Look at that drone boat!  Flaunting its solar panels open to the blue sky!  Is that San Diego back there?   I hoped it might be a drone boat because those things sticking up were drone pipes but no; they are antennae.

But that drone boat can do lots of stuff.  It can check out things in dangerous places and also things in boring far away places and also just things needing to be checked out like the beach in San Diego.  It can bring bombs to bombable objects and drop them off.  Or supplies to suppliable objects and drop those off.  Keep those two jobs straight, drone boat!  It can do those things on its own or by remote control.

It cannot play Amazing Grace for a burial at sea.  Yet.

Comment: Thanks. How effective are Marine drones for a Naval defense force of a country?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar - I think they would be all you need.  Pretty sure.  Maybe some frogmen too because I love those frogmen but at a 1 frogman (or frogwoman!) / 100 Marine drone ratio.   Frogpersons.  Those are what is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the information on Frogman and their operations in Naval defense forces.

Answer (score 1):

In a modern conflict, the easier you can be seen, the faster you will die. Current solar panels are large flat, very reflective, and easily seen.

Perhaps a new generation of completely absorbent material using thermal solar energy might be useful, but I am not aware of any such material in wide spread use.